# SailsJS App running on Amazon Ubuntu EC2 web server

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, sails.js, portforwarding

I just started to host my SailsJS app on EC2 and I'm struggling so much. I cannot get the app to run on port 80. So what I did was I changed the default apache listening port of 80 to 8080.

But still Sails cannot be lifted and I get this error.

```
warn: error raised: Error: listen EACCES

error: Server doesn't seem to be starting.
error: 
error: Troubleshooting tips:
error: 
error:  -> Do you have permission to use port 80 on this system? (you might try `sudo`)
error: 
error:  -> Is something else already running on port 80 ?
error: 
error:  -> Are you deploying on a platform that requires an explicit hostname, like OpenShift?
error:     (Try setting the `explicitHost` config to the hostname where the server will be accessible.)
error:     (e.g. `mydomain.com` or `183.24.244.42`)
```

As it says I tried Sudo, But then the app starts. Cool.

Then I get all these errors on the terminal

```
warn: websocket connection invalid
warn: websocket connection invalid
warn: websocket connection invalid
warn: websocket connection invalid
```

And this error on my browser console

WebSocket connection to 'ws://mywebsite.co/socket.io/1/websocket/GXGSRKCiYhST-7CMcXkm?__sails_io_sdk_version=0.10.0&__sails_io_sdk_platform=browser&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

This is the ubuntu > netstat if that help in anywhy to understand

```
$ netstat
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         localhost:51432         TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         localhost:51433         TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0    308 ip-172-31-28-139.ap:ssh 121.75.215.208:55402    ESTABLISHED
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  4      [ ]         DGRAM                    8490     /dev/log
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8369     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7920     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8392     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9978     
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    9832     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8391     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9979     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8403     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    7519     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8406     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    8696     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8483     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8484     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7890     
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    7520     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8405     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7468     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9973     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7481     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9972
```

It seems like there are unclosed connections from the app

As you may see here. So the app is never closed because of the web sockets

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp      584      0 ip-173-31-28-139.a:1337 121.75.215.208:57749    CLOSE_WAIT  6468/node       
tcp      493      0 ip-173-31-28-139.a:1337 121.75.215.208:57748    CLOSE_WAIT  6468/node       
tcp        0    596 ip-173-31-28-139.ap:ssh 121.75.215.208:56740    ESTABLISHED -               
tcp      449      0 ip-173-31-28-139.a:1337 121.75.215.208:57872    ESTABLISHED -               
tcp      493      0 ip-173-31-28-139.a:1337 121.75.215.208:57745    CLOSE_WAIT  6468/node       
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         localhost:51494         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp        1      0 ip-173-31-28-139.a:1337 121.75.215.208:57873    CLOSE_WAIT  -               
tcp        7      0 ip-173-31-28-139.a:1337 121.75.215.208:57780    CLOSE_WAIT  6468/node       
tcp      499      0 ip-173-31-28-139.a:1337 121.75.215.208:57744    CLOSE_WAIT  6468/node       
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         localhost:51493         ESTABLISHED -               
tcp      584      0 ip-173-31-28-139.a:1337 121.75.215.208:57746    CLOSE_WAIT  6468/node       
tcp        0      0 localhost:51494         localhost:mysql         ESTABLISHED 6468/node       
tcp        0      0 localhost:51493         localhost:mysql         ESTABLISHED 6468/node       
tcp        0      0 ip-173-31-28-139.ap:ssh 121.75.215.208:55402    ESTABLISHED -               
tcp      499      0 ip-173-31-28-139.a:1337 121.75.215.208:57747    CLOSE_WAIT  6468/node
```

Please help if you have done this in your life. I'm happy to delete all my configuration and start from scratch.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this one?

Answer (score 0):

From the fact that you mentioned "default Apache port", I'm guessing you're starting with an AMI that's not necessarily optimal for Node apps.  I would suggest starting with the [Bitnami Node.js AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B008AT4Q7G) on EC2.  I haven't had any problems setting up Sails apps on EC2 instances using that AMI.  It probably doesn't come pre-installed with MySQL, but that's what `apt-get` is for, right?